# コマンドラインで読み込んだファイルに上書きするには

Tags: linux, unix

```
$ cat hoge.txt > hoge.txt
```

これを実行すると、「`hoge.txt`の中身がそのまま`hoge.txt`に書き出されて結果的に中身は同じになる」と思っていたのですが、実行してみるとファイルの中身が空になり、容量も0バイトになってしまいます。

他のコマンドでも同様に読み込みファイルにたいして`>`をつかって上書きしようとすると中身が消えてしまいます。

上書きしたい場合はどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

Comment: このコマンドを実行する目的は何でしょうか？（知的好奇心という意味では興味ありますが）。上書きとは言いますが内容の変更を伴わないのであれば、例えば`touch hoge.txt`でタイムスタンプだけ更新する方法もあります。

Answer (score 11):

シェルがコマンドラインを解釈した後、`hoge.txt` をオープンして 0 バイトにしてから `cat` を起動するので当然の結果です。実行したいコマンドラインの前に `hoge.txt` を一時ファイルにコピーして利用するか、実行結果を一時ファイルに出力したあと上書きする必要があります。

moreutils の `sponge`(1) が利用できる環境ならば、一時ファイルは不要で次のように実行できます。

```
cat hoge.txt |sponge hoge.txt
```

なお、ほかの回答にある元ファイルを一旦削除する方法は、元ファイルのファイル所有者とアクセス権が失なわれる可能性があるので注意が必要です。

Answer (score 5):

黒魔術的ではありますが、以下のようにするとUNIXとシェルの機能のみで中間ファイルを利用することなく実現できます。

```
(rm -f hoge.txt && cat > hoge.txt) < hoge.txt
```

cat だと分かりにくいので、`sort` を使った例:

```
% cat hoge.txt
3
1
2
% (rm -f hoge.txt && sort > hoge.txt) < hoge.txt
% cat hoge.txt
1
2
3
```

オープンしたファイルを削除しても、クローズされるまではファイル本体が残っている (読み書き可能) であることを利用 (悪用?) しています。

参考: https://twitter.com/kuwashima/status/854716064109699072

Answer (score 1):

リダイレクトはコマンドが実行される前に shell が処理してしまってますから、コマンドが実行された時には既にファイルは空になっています。

出力を一旦別ファイルに格納するしかないのでは?

```
cat hoge.txt > tmp
mv tmp hoge.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`GNU cat` だとその構文はエラーになります。

```
$ cat hoge.txt > hoge.txt
cat: hoge.txt: input file is output file
```

次のようなやり方はどうでしょう。

```
$ cat hoge.txt | bash -c 'cat - > hoge.txt'
```

Comment: 運がよければうまくいく場合もあるでしょうが、駄目な場合もあります。恐らく `hoge.txt` のサイズが大きいほど失敗しやすくなるでしょうね。

Comment: 基本的にリダイレクト先のことをプロセスは知らないのでGNUのcatが検出できるのが不思議だったのですが、ファイルディスクリプタから調べたfstatのdeviceやらi-nodeやらを見てがんばっているみたいですね。試してみた限りでは、ext3,4 では出来ましたが、btrfs,xfs では駄目でした。
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/cat.c;h=995dc616c8221333c525c6bbabb792c4983d7e89;hb=HEAD#l691